# How to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: boot

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS but cannot get beyond the login screen. Have tried three recommended fixes relating to NVIDIA without any change and now hope to reinstall the O/S as others said it might help.

I have downloaded ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso from the Ubuntu Download site onto my wife's Apple which is our only working machine now.

I have copied it to a Sandisk drive and tried to use that to reinstall Ubuntu on my preferred machine. Have set the USB drive as the preferred boot drive but my computer is reluctant to install it as "no mountable file systems"

I really do not want to go back to Windows after six years of sequential Ubuntu O/S's but it seems this login defect on 16.04.1 cannot be overcome. So this is a cry for anyone out there who has solved the login problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I hope when you say you put it on a USB, you don't mean the ISO file :)

If you did, no harm done.

An ISO file is a Disk image, and to put it on a USB, you have to write the *contents* of the ISO on the USB, not the ISO itself.

**Process**

So you can do it from the command prompt on a Mac like this:

`$ diskutil list`

Find your USB drive in the list.  It will look something like "/dev/disk2"

`$ diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2`

Unmount the disk.

`$ sudo dd bs=4M if=ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/disk2 status=progress`

Write the ISO *contents* to the USB.

Done :)

Try booting that, and see how it goes.

Good luck!

**Notes:**

- `bs=4M` tells dd to use a 4Mb block size
- `if=` is your input file
- `of=` is your destination
- `status=progress` should update you a little during the process

Comment: That's very helpful and I can do those things but there's one difficulty. The Mac says 4M is an illegal numeric value. I tried 8M and 2M but they too are illegal. Not sure what I have done wrong this time and embarrassed to call on your kind assistance yet again. Is there another block size suitable?

Comment: Thats ok, you can do it without the `bs=` altogether.  Like this: `sudo dd  if=ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/disk2 status=progress` I'm not certain the _bs_ switch actually works on a Mac :)

Comment: It says dd unknown operand status. I wish it did not. This is a Mac she bought this Spring so its quite new.

Comment: Ok, try this:  `sudo dd if='ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso' of=/dev/disk2 status=progress bs=1m` or variations. Basically, it's saying it doesnt understand what you're trying to input or output.  Remember you also have to be in the directory that contains the ISO file on the mac.  So if you downloaded it to /home/user/downloads, that's where you need to run the command from. :)

Comment: That seemed to do something but I don't know what it was. The DOS prompt disappeared with the computer name. I thought the Mac was doing something internally but after 20 minutes I guessed it was not. My problem is I don't know Mac language. There's no dir no cd download so I don't know how to get to the download directory to type the command you have kindly drafted for me

Comment: It could take around 5-10 minutes to write the ISO to the USB.  Try to boot from the USB now.

Comment: My notebook is now set to boot off the USB. I put the data drive in and the notebook ran an Intel program but finally reverted to the old Linux 16.04 version with the login problem. It seems the unmounted iso file has not yet been transferred to the finger drive.

Comment: Ok, the only other option is to use unetbootin http://unetbootin.github.io/. Get the mac version and install it, then follow the instructions here: https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Comment: Thanks for all your help. You have been very patient and I am much obliged to you. Fingers crossed this new process will work.

Comment: No problems.  Good luck!